# How can I get the selected cells text from UITableViewController B to display in a cell on UITableViewController A?

Tags: swift

I would like for the user to tap a cell within `UITableViewController` B and then have the text from the cell sent to display in a cell inside of `UITableViewController` A which would replace its default text. However I am having trouble doing so. Both of the `UITableViewController` A & B are in a `UINavigationController`. `selectedName` is the String I would like to send from B to A

Here is the code from `UITableViewController`B `didSelectRowAt`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BBcell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        selectedName = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        print(selectedName)
        let infoTVC = InfoTableViewController()
        infoTVC.name = selectedName

    }
```

Here is the code from `UITableViewController` A

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Choose Name" // This is where I set the default text
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
    }
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: How are these `UITableViewcontroller`s displayed? Does one push onto the nav controller so the user only sees one at a time, or are they somehow displayed simultaneously? Ultimately, though, it comes down to your hierarchy and probably using delegates. You'll basically need to find a common ancestry between the two table view controllers and configure them to communicate through their common ancestor, most likely using the delegate pattern.

Comment: I am fairly new to Swift. View Controller B is fullscreen and presented on top of A.

Comment: okay, so how is your data setup, cause you can use an Array, save it with UserDefaults and load a separate array using the same UserDefaults "file path".

Comment: "View Controller B is fullscreen and presented on top of A" - do you mean you are using the navigation controller to push VC-B onto the stack? In that case, the common ancestor would be the navigation controller. Basically, B tells nav "hey I'm changed x at index x to y", then nav tells A "reload index x", passing data along if necessary.

Comment: @mredig Yes I meant I am using the navigation controller to push VC-B onto the stack. Could you link an example or code snippet ? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @jbiser361 How can I save the to Array to UserDefaults? (Im still learning swift)

Comment: give me more info about your array, is it an object array or an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very rudimentary example that has many shortcomings and utilizes some practices breaking SOLID principles, but fundamentally should work. Don't take this as the final end all answer, but instead as a starting point to move forward from:

```swift
import UIKit

// declare the delegate protocol
protocol TableViewControllerSubclassBDelegate: AnyObject {
    func tableViewControllerB(_ controller: TableViewControllerSubclassB, touched indexPath: IndexPath, withStringInfo newStringValue: String)
}

// table view controller where the content ends up
class TableViewControllerSubclassA: UITableViewController {
    var tableArrayContents: [String] = []
}

// table view controller where the user touches an entry
class TableViewControllerSubclassB: UITableViewController {
    //...
    weak var delegate: TableViewControllerSubclassBDelegate?

    //...
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // this is quite prone to fail if everything is not perfectly set - beware
        guard let stringInfo = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel?.text else { return }
        delegate?.tableViewControllerB(self, touched: indexPath, withStringInfo: stringInfo)
    }
}

// you'll need to subclass your navigation controller with something like this
class NavigationControllerSubclass: UINavigationController {

    // force unwrap is generally frowned upon. there are better solutions, but this is a simplified answer
    var tvcA: TableViewControllerSubclassA!
    var tvcB: TableViewControllerSubclassB!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // populate the table view controller properties - not the cleanest way
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            if let typeA = viewController as? TableViewControllerSubclassA {
                tvcA = typeA
            } else if let typeB = viewController as? TableViewControllerSubclassB {
                tvcB = typeB
            }
        }
        tvcB.delegate = self
    }
}

// conforming to delegates/protocols in an extension is a great way to organize your code
extension NavigationControllerSubclass: TableViewControllerSubclassBDelegate {
    func tableViewControllerB(_ controller: TableViewControllerSubclassB, touched indexPath: IndexPath, withStringInfo newStringValue: String) {

        tvcA.tableArrayContents[indexPath.row] = newStringValue
        tvcA.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        // you could also go the heavyhanded approach of tvcA.tableView.reloadData() if necessary
    }
}
```